# android:checkableBehavior set programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

I am creating a Menu in Android XML and adding via code a submenu. Now I want that only one menu-point to be checked. In XML it would be `android:checkableBehavior="single"`. But how can I realize this in code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
MySubMenu.setGroupCheckable(int groupId, boolean checkable, boolean exclusive);
```

exclusive = true //to pick only one menu-point as android:checkableBehavior="single"

For example:

```
MySubMenu.setGroupCheckable(0, true, true);
```

*Add this function after all your submenu items were defined